# Discrete Math: True or false x=a ∨ x≠a

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this example in one of my discrete math courses and I`m trying to understand the answer it: Suppose the following two statements (x=a) ∨ (x≠a) is it true or false?
I know that it`s false when only both operators are false, but I don't know in this case if it can be the case

Comment: Think about what it says: "$x$ is either equal to $a$ or not" .. does that strike you as true or false?

Comment: That statement seems to be ambiguous, what are $x$ and $a$?

Comment: @user340297 Do we need to know what $a$ and $x$ are in order to answer the question?

Comment: @Bram28 Of course, would the statement make sense if $x=(0,1)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $y=0$?

Comment: @user340297 I see, you're saying that for some choices of $a$ and $x$ the statement $a = x$ has no truth-value at all ... Well, we're probably overthinking this

Comment: So than I suppose the statement is true since one of the two statements is true.. example we say x =2 and a =2 than we have: 2=2 or 2≠2.. we have one of the two being true therefore the disjunction is true

Comment: @SoftDeveloper Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have $x=a$ or $x\neq a$. If $x=a$, then $x=a\ \vee\ x\neq a$ is true since $x=a$ is true; otherwise, if $x\neq a$, then $x=a\ \vee\ x\neq a$ is true.

In general, given a property $P$, $P \vee \lnot P$ is always true; similarly, $P \wedge \lnot P$ is always false.

Answer (score 0):

For any sentence $P, P \vee \lnot P$ is a tautology and is therefore true.
Consider the two possible truth values of $P$.  Normally your sentence would have an implied quatification of $\forall x,a$ before it to bind the variables.